# PHPMailer - file attachment ERR

Tags: php, html, phpmailer

i've search here but i didnt find anything that solve the problem... hope someone could help me please....

i'm using PHPMailer to send mails and i want to add option to attach PDF Files that's my code:

**HTML (simplfied):**

```
<form method="post" action="contact/submit.php">
    <input type="email" name="email" value="<?php echo $supmail; ?>" size="80">
    <input type="text" name="ccmail" value="<?php echo implode(', ', $final);?>" size="80">
    <input type="text" style="font-size:11" name="subject" id="subject" value="ORDER" size="80">
    <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="100000">
    <input type="file" name="userfile" size="55" style="font-size:10;" accept="application/pdf">
    <textarea rows="7" name="message" id="message" cols="85" style="font-size: 11"><?php echo $newstr; ?></textarea>
 <div class="g-recaptcha" style="text-align:center;" data-sitekey="<?= CONTACTFORM_RECAPTCHA_SITE_KEY ?>">
    <button class="button">Send</button>
</form>
```

**submit.php:**

```
<?php
 require('db.php');

$target_dir = __DIR__."/uploads/";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
$uploadOk = 1;
$imageFileType = strtolower(pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION));

if (file_exists($target_file)) {
  echo "קובץ קיים.";
  $uploadOk = 0;
}

if($imageFileType != "pdf") {
  echo "ניתן להעלות רק קבצי PDF";
  $uploadOk = 0;
}

if ($uploadOk == 0) {
  echo "הקובץ לא עלה.";
} else {
  if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
echo $target_file;
  } else {
    echo "שגיאה בהעלאת הקובץ";
  }
}

require_once __DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php';
require_once __DIR__.'/functions.php';
require_once __DIR__.'/config.php';

session_start();

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] != 'POST') {
    redirectWithError("The form must be submitted with POST data.");
}

// Do some validation, check to make sure the name, email and message are valid.
if (empty($_POST['g-recaptcha-response'])) {
    redirectWithError("נא להשלים בדיקת רובוט");
}

$recaptcha = new \ReCaptcha\ReCaptcha(CONTACTFORM_RECAPTCHA_SECRET_KEY);
$resp = $recaptcha->verify($_POST['g-recaptcha-response'], $_REQUEST['REMOTE_ADDR']);

if (!$resp->isSuccess()) {
    $errors = $resp->getErrorCodes();
    $error = $errors[0];

    $recaptchaErrorMapping = [
        'missing-input-secret' => 'לא נשלח קוד.',
        'invalid-input-secret' => 'הקוד לא נכון.',
        'missing-input-response' => 'לא נשלח אימות.',
        'invalid-input-response' => 'שגיאה בקבלת תשובת אימות.',
        'bad-request' => 'שגיאה לא ידועה.',
        'timeout-or-duplicate' => 'פג תוקף, נסה שוב',
    ];

    $errorMessage = $recaptchaErrorMapping[$error];
    redirectWithError("יש לנסות שוב אימות: ".$errorMessage);
}
if (empty($_POST['email'])) {
    redirectWithError("אנא הזן כתובת דואר אלקטורני עבור הספק");
}

if (empty($_POST['subject'])) {
    redirectWithError("אנא הזן נושא להזמנה");
}

if (empty($_POST['message'])) {
    redirectWithError("אנא הזן הודעה לספק");
}

if (!filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
    redirectWithError("נא להזין כתובת דואר אלקטרונית חוקית");
}

if (strlen($_POST['message']) < 5) {
    redirectWithError("חובה להזין לפחות 5 תויים בהודעה");
}

// Everything seems OK, time to send the email.

$mail = new \PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer(true);

try {
    //Server settings
$tomail = $_POST['email'];
$toname = $_POST['suppl'];
$ccmail = $_POST['ccmail'];
$nametoconf = $_POST['confby'];
$orderid = $_POST['orderid'];
$toname2 = "מכללת השף";
    $mail->SMTPDebug = 2;
    $mail->isSMTP();
    $mail->Host = CONTACTFORM_SMTP_HOSTNAME;
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
    $mail->Username = CONTACTFORM_SMTP_USERNAME;
    $mail->Password = CONTACTFORM_SMTP_PASSWORD;
    $mail->SMTPSecure = CONTACTFORM_SMTP_ENCRYPTION;
    $mail->Port = CONTACTFORM_SMTP_PORT;
    $mail->setFrom(CONTACTFORM_FROM_ADDRESS, $toname2);
    $mail->addAddress($tomail, $toname);
    $ccmailto = explode(',', $ccmail);
    foreach($ccmailto as $ccmailtof)
    {
        $mail->AddCC($ccmailtof);
    }
    // Content
    $mail->Subject = "".$_POST['subject'];
    $mail->Body    = <<<EOT
{$_POST['message']}
EOT;
    $mail->AddAttachment($target_file);
    $mail->send();
    redirectSuccess();
} catch (Exception $e) {
    redirectWithError("שגיאה בעת ניסיון שליחת ההזמנה: ".$mail->ErrorInfo);
}
?>
```

when i'm tring to send mail witout the attachment  works great.
when i add the attachment i get "Could not access file:"

thank you

Comment: Please share more details. The code does not contain any occurence of that error message

Comment: @NicoHaase i've updated the PHP code here, it's the full one... i get err "Could not access file:" because the file just didnt uploaded and he can't find the file... but when i try the upload code alone in different page without the PHPMAILER code the file is uploaded great...

Answer (score 1):

This code is unsafe:

```
$mail->AddAttachment($_FILES['uploaded_file']['tmp_name'], $_FILES['userfile']['name']);
```

As per [the file upload example provided with PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/send_file_upload.phps) and [the PHP docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php), you need to validate what's in `$_FILES` before trusting it.

Further to that, the `addAttachment` method returns a tru/false status value if it can find and read the file, so check that – don't assume that it's worked.